# Fortran running error

Tags: fortran

I have a Fortran code that I have to run but unfortunately I don't have any experience with Fortran. I tried to run the code using different Fortran version and nothing works.

Here is the link for the code: http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/summaries/adpw.

It would be great if someone could tell me which Fortran version should I use.

Here are the details:

When I try to run with gfortran:

```
gfortran numcbas.f < numcbas_c.data 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

and when I run with g77:

```
g77 numcbas.f < numcbas_c.data

ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.10

ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in __start from /usr/lib/crt1.o. 

To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
```

And here is start of the code:

```
  program NUMCBAS

  IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)

 MAIN DRIVING ROUTINE

  CHARACTER*120 TITLE
  DIMENSION IBUG(3),HRXS(10),IRXS(10)
  COMMON /BASCON/ HRX(10),IRX(10),NIX,IRA
  DATA TITLE /'        '/
  DATA HRXS/1.D-02,2.D-02,2.605D-02,7*0.D0/
  DATA IRXS/30,120,500,7*0/,IBUG/3*0/

  INTEGER :: NFTA=6,LUNUMB=13, LVAL=0
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: BTOL=0.2D0, TINY=1.D-11
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: ECMAX=10.D0, RLIM=10.D0, CHARGE=0.D0

  NAMELIST /INPUT/ TITLE,LUNUMB,NIX,IRX,HRX,lval,IBUG,BTOL,
 *                 TINY,ECMAX,RLIM,CHARGE

  WRITE (6,1000)
```

and the input file:

```
&INPUT 
TITLE='IONIC TARGET',
lval=0, ECMAX = 5.00D0,  
RLIM = 12.0D0, CHARGE=1.0D0,/
```

Comment: Post the code here. Don't just link it, please.

Comment: You should post the code here. How it "doesn't work"? Does it print something? I don't have any experience with mind reading.

Comment: What did you try to get the code running? What went wrong? Any error messages? Which Fortran "versions" did you use?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are completely misunderstanding tho processes of compilation and running.

These lines are suspicious:

```
gfortran numcbas.f < numcbas_c.data

g77 numcbas.f < numcbas_c.data
```

There is no reason to redirect a data file to the compiler command. The compiler first has to create an executable program which you then can run with your data. Normally, a file `./a.out` is created and you then run it

`./a.out < some_data_to_stdin`

It is very strange that you get a Segmentation fault from running gfortran without any other error message. Are you sure the commands you show above are exactly what you are running?

Comment: If I run gfortran numcbas.f with gfortran-4.7, I get: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.0.0
numcbas.f:3.33:

      IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)                               
                                 1
Error: Parameter 'a' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
f951: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction: 4
f951: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6
 and with gfortran-5.0, I get: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: @RoniPozner Why didn't you include that in your question? Do that now and give it some formatting, it is very difficult to read it from your comment. And include the FULL message and FULL compilation command.